# split a string with max character limit

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to split a string into many strings (List) with each one having a maximum limit of characters. So say if I had a string of 500 characters, and I want each string to have a max of 75, there would be 7 strings, and the last one would not have a full 75.

I've tried some of the examples I have found on stackoverflow, but they 'truncate' the results. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't String have a substring method?

Comment: It would help me if you provided a couple test cases that demonstrate what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own extension method to do something like that

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitOnLength(this string input, int length)
    {
        int index = 0;
        while (index < input.Length)
        {
            if (index + length < input.Length)
                yield return input.Substring(index, length);
            else
                yield return input.Substring(index);

            index += length;
        }
    }
}
```

And then you could call it like this

```
string temp = new string('@', 500);

string[] array = temp.SplitOnLength(75).ToArray();

foreach (string x in array)
    Console.WriteLine(x);
```

Comment: what is the '@' in your string temp = new string('@', 500); ?
Also where does the actual string parameter that i'm splitting go into?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a little cleaner than the other answers:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(string s, int length)
    {
        while (s.Length > length)
        {
            yield return s.Substring(0, length);
            s = s.Substring(length);
        }

        if (s.Length > 0) yield return s;            
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would tackle this with a loop using C# String.Substring method.

Note that this isn't exact code, but you get the idea.

```
var myString = "hello world";
List<string> list = new List();
int maxSize
while(index < myString.Length())
{
  if(index + maxSize > myString.Length())
  {
    // handle last case
    list.Add(myString.Substring(index));
    break;
  }
  else
  {
    list.Add(myString.Substring(index,maxSize));
    index+= maxSize;
   }
}
```

Comment: You still need to add that last sub-75 character string ;)

Comment: sorry, thats what the //comment was for. I was just being lazy :)

Answer (score 1):

When you say split, are you referring to the split function? If not, something like this will work:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
string s = "";
int num = 75;
while (s.Length > 0)
{
    list.Add(s.Substring(0, num));
    s = s.Remove(0, num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming maybe a delimiter - like space character.

search on the string (instr) until you find the next position of the delimiter.

if that is < your substring length (75) then append to the current substring.

if not, start a new substring.

special case - if there is no delimiter in the entire substring - then you need to define what happens - like add a '-' then continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string SplitByLength(string s, int length)
    {
        ArrayList sArrReturn = new ArrayList();
        String[] sArr = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        foreach (string sconcat in sArr)
        {
            if (((String.Join(" ", sArrReturn.ToArray()).Length + sconcat.Length)+1) < length)
                sArrReturn.Add(sconcat);
            else
                break;
        }
        return String.Join(" ", sArrReturn.ToArray());
    }

    public static string SplitByLengthOld(string s, int length)
    {
        try
        {
            string sret = string.Empty;
            String[] sArr = s.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (string sconcat in sArr)
            {
                if ((sret.Length + sconcat.Length + 1) < length)
                    sret = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", sret, string.IsNullOrEmpty(sret) ? string.Empty : " ", sconcat);
            }
            return sret;
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Sankarann, The SplitByLength can be used for .NET 4.0+ and SplitByLengthOld for all type of .NET framework.