# Split string data to pages

Tags: c#, jquery, webbrowser-control

I used [booklet plug in](http://builtbywill.com/code/booklet/demos/hovers) for make a book flip effect for my `Web Browser` content,so every thing is fine.

I retrieve my text data from db i want to write a function that aromatically convert text (that already retrieved from db)to pages for example if my text amount is
is larger than a page it's put rest of text in the next page and so on.

**Html Code**

```
<html >
<head>
    <!-- page css -->
    <link href="Booklet%20-%20jQuery%20Plugin_files/base0000.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection, tv">
    <link href="Booklet%20-%20jQuery%20Plugin_files/booklet0.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection, tv">

    <!-- required files for booklet -->
    <script src="Booklet%20-%20jQuery%20Plugin_files/jquery00.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Booklet%20-%20jQuery%20Plugin_files/jquery-u.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Booklet%20-%20jQuery%20Plugin_files/jquery01.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Booklet%20-%20jQuery%20Plugin_files/jquery02.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Booklet%20-%20jQuery%20Plugin_files/jquery00.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection, tv">

    <!-- basic initialization -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function mm() {
        $('#mybook').booklet();
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body >
<div id="mybook">
<div>page 1 content<div>//If my page content was larger than page put rest of text to next page
<div>page 2 content<div>
<div>page 3 content<div>
.
.
.
<div>
</body>
</html>
```

how can i do this?

Comment: How do you retrieve your data from the db?

Comment: @derape:i have a tbl of book content so i retrieve for example chapter 1 from db i want to show this amount of text in to web browser with flip book effect.i want to show this chapter to some pages but i don't know how convert this chapter to some pages.

Comment: yea I got that, my question was more like how you retrieve the data exactly? How do you get the data to your page? AJAX? You'd have split the text at the time you are iserting the data into your page...

Comment: @derape:i have a webbrowser control in my form i fill it with some raw text

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you would have to do something like this once the document is loaded:

```
var bookDiv = yourWebBrowserControl.Document.GetElementById["mybook"];

IEnumerable<string> theBook = getTheDataFromDb();
var sites = SplitTheBookIntoSites();

foreach (var site in sites)
{
  var bookSiteDiv = yourWebBrowserControl.Document.CreateElement("div");
  bookSiteDiv.InnerText = theSite;
  bookDiv.AppendChild(bookSiteDiv);
}
```

For splitting the string you can use one of the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081492/split-a-string-with-max-character-limit). In order to have a fixed string size on each site, you would have to choose a [monospace font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) like Courier